# git: determine if there are file that are not on repo, but should be added

Tags: linux, git, bash, windows-7, git-bash

I have a repository where Git shows that:

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   pom.xml
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   src/main/java/fr/SomeClass.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   README.md
#
```

I'd like to know in reasonably quick manner if:

- there are file staged for commit (here: `pom.xml`)
- not staged for commit (here: `SomeClass.java`)
- untracked files (here: `README.md`)

I'm using the following command for the first case:

```
    git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet --exit-code       2> /dev/null || w='*'
    git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet --exit-code HEAD  2> /dev/null || h='+'
```

But when only a file is not staged, `w` and `h` are filled with `*` and `+`.

```
$ git status --porcelain
M  pom.xml
 M src/main/java/fr/SomeClass.java
?? toto
```

Would work, but it print to much, and I'm looking for something that simplies print a number of items, like:

```
1 1 1
```

Where each number is respectively staged, not staged and untracked.

My purpose here is to print whether my repositories are changed, and what is changed. I don't want to parse the whole output (that would work with `grep` and such, but I want to avoid that).

Oh, and I tagged it Windows because I'm looking for a solution that would work on Linux but also on Windows with git-bash. Bash 4 based solution, without an explicit way to do it in Bash 3, will not help me that much.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to avoid using "grep". It seems using "grep" on the output of "git status --porcelain" is pretty easy.

Comment: I know I could use `grep` and `sed` (to truncate/limit porcelain output to 2 chars), but I am looking for a clever way (like some git command).

Comment: What about files that are marked MM (or similar) how do they get counted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

let untracked_count=0 worktree_count=0 staged_count=0 other_count=0
git status -z --porcelain > status.tmp
while IFS= read -n 2 stat; IFS= read -d '' line; do
  case "$stat" in
    (\?\?) (( untracked_count++ )) ;;
    (\ ?)  (( worktree_count++  )) ;;
    (?\ )  (( staged_count++    )) ;;
    (M?)   (( worktree_count++ )) ; (( staged_count++ )) ;;
    *)    (( other_count++     )) ;;
  esac
done < status.tmp
```

Read `git status -z --porcelain` output with bash builtin `read` to grab the information we care about and then count what we see. `IFS` on the first read is necessary to avoid the shell dumping leading or trailing spaces. `IFS` on the second read isn't strictly necessary in this case but is the "read input by lines" pattern I use.

Use of bash 4 would allow a less duplicated set of case labels (through use of `;;&`).

**Side note:** on Linux, it can be done like this:

```
while IFS= read -n 2 stat; IFS= read -d '' line; do
  ..
done < <(git status -z --porcelain)
```

But the `<(...)` redirect is not implemented in Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: So that I understand, the first read read only two char, the second read the rest of the line ? And `IFS=` would mean use `\0` ?

Comment: Yes, the first read reads the first two characters of the status output (the status codes). The second read reads the rest of the line. `IFS=` tells read not to word split the line at all. `-d ''` tells read to use `\0` as the delimiter.

Comment: Ok. It worked, thanks! I did not know that you could redirect a stream (`< <(...)`) in that way.

Comment: `<(...)` is process substitution. That is simply redirecting standard input from the sub-process (much like a pipe). In fact, if you didn't need to retain the counts after the while loop ended you could just use a pipe for this.

Comment: For the record the code I posted originally worked just fine. I tested it. The edited code here is also perfectly valid and accounts for information about the actual need that wasn't made apparent in the OP originally.

Comment: I don't know why it works in a standalone way (I tried in a single bash file, outside of any function), but it failed in my function however using `(( worktree_count++ , staged_count++ ))` worked (as explained in man: `expr1 , expr2`).

Comment: No. It would seem that `((e++ f++)` in fact does not work. I must just not have hit that branch. My apologies.